# Unwanted rows in a table layout

Tags: java, android, android-tablayout, tablelayout

In my adapter class, I want to make a table layout with only 4 rows to represent my 4 values in different 4 rows.

Everything is good except that the number of rows are tripled (12 rows) but I designed it to have only 4 rows as in the code below:

```
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    final arraybill.ViewHolder holder;

    if (view == null) {
        holder = new arraybill.ViewHolder();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_bill, null);
        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
        holder.ll = (TableLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.displayLinear);

        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (arraybill.ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    // Set the results into TextViews



    label = new String[] {"A","B","C","D"};
    value = new String[]{modelList.get(0).getbill(),modelList.get(0).getaccepting(),
            modelList.get(0).getdeclining(),modelList.get(0).getwaiting()};



    for (int i = 0; i < label.length; i++) {

        TableRow row= new TableRow(mContext);
        row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        row.setLayoutParams(lp);

        tv = new TextView(mContext);
        tv.setPadding(20,10,5,10);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        tv.setText(label[i]);

        tv2 =new TextView(mContext);
        tv2.setText("");
        tv2.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
        tv2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

        tv3 =new TextView(mContext);
        tv3.setText(value[i]);
        tv3.setPadding(5,10,20,10);
        tv3.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

        row.addView(tv3,0);
        row.addView(tv2,1);
        row.addView(tv,2);

        row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border);
        holder.ll.setColumnShrinkable(0,true);
        holder.ll.addView(row,i);
   }

    //...

    return view;
}
```

Comment: You see 12 rows when you expect three. What are the contents of those 12 rows? Do rows duplicate and, if so, how. A posted image would help.

Comment: Yes, they are the expected four rows and tripled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put `holder.ll.removeAllViews();` before your `for` cycle:

```
label = new String[] {"A","B","C","D"};
value = new String[]{modelList.get(0).getbill(),modelList.get(0).getaccepting(),
        modelList.get(0).getdeclining(),modelList.get(0).getwaiting()};

holder.ll.removeAllViews();

for (int i = 0; i < label.length; i++) {

    TableRow row= new TableRow(mContext);
    row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    row.setLayoutParams(lp);

    //...

}
```

Comment: holder.ll = (TableLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.displayLinear);
and I'm using baseadapter

Comment: in what method do you execute this code with `for` cycle?

Comment: public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)

Comment: I updated my answer. Could your provide full code of your adapter?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know what exactly was the problem, because I don't see where you call this method. But it seems as this method were called few times and TableLayout were adding every time the same rows.

Answer (score 0):

Im not an expert or anything so my "help" could be totally wrong but i try : label.length is 4, so you create 4X3 tv,tv2,tv3 and add them. Thats why you have 12 rows and not 4 i guess.

Comment: tv ,tv2 ,tv3 are textviews on the same row